# Using class_eval to overwrite an association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

I have a Message model that has the following relationships:

```
belongs_to :sender, Class: "User"
belongs_to :recipient, Class: "User"
```

I'm attempting to use class_eval to overwrite the recipient method in certain cases.

This works:

```
def update_recipient(message, recipient_addition = nil)
  message.class_eval <<-EVAL
    def recipient
      "test"
    end
  EVAL
end
```

message.recipient => "test"

However, this doesn't:

```
def update_recipient(message, recipient_addition = nil)
  message.class_eval <<-EVAL
    def recipient
      [#{message.recipient}, #{recipient_addition}]
    end
  EVAL
end

(eval):3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ']'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `#` is misinterpreted as a comment character, discarding the rest of the line.  The `#{}` are expected to be interpolated inside double quotes, though there doesn't seem to be a reason to put these in `#{}` right now as they are just simple string values.

```
["#{message.recipient}", "#{recipient_addition}"]
```

... unless you're planning something like:

```
["To: #{message.recipient}", "CC: #{recipient_addition}"]
```

Comment: What, in your opinion, is the best way to return the array with user objects as show?

Comment: Those look to be objects you are returning, so if you want to return _string_ values, do something like `[message.recipient.email, recipient_addition.email]` (assuming they have email properties).  If you want to return the _objects_, just return them directly via `[message.recipient, recipient_addition]`

Comment: Unfortunately, recipient_addition isn't in scope of that class_eval block.